# Design IntegerTracker class with methods add, get_max, get_min, get_mean, get_mode. All O(1) runtime

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

This is one of an interview question. You need to design a class with the methods above in any language of your choosing. Ideally I'd like to do it in PHP, JavaScript or Ruby.

I was playing around with the below code related to temperature, but would like to see if there are better options available?

```
def insert(temperature)

# for mode
if @temperature_hash[temperature]
  @temperature_hash[temperature] += 1
  if @temperature_hash[temperature] > @max_occurrence
    @max_occurrence = @temperature_hash[temperature]
    @mode = temperature
  end
else
  @temperature_hash[temperature] = 1
end

# for min and max
@max = temperature if temperature > @max
@min = temperature if temperature < @min

# for mean
@sum += temperature
@count += 1
@mean = @sum/@count
end
```

Comment: Better with respect to what?

Comment: Better with respect to not having to use built in ruby's temperature object, how can this be redone using JS or php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to note.

First, I don't see where you ever set the original value of `max_occurrence`. The first time you call `insert`, you add a new value to the map, but you never set `max_occurrence`. So if I were to query the mode after the first item added, I'd get an incorrect value.

I think rearranging your code will solve that problem:

(Please excuse any syntax errors, as I'm not particularly proficient in Ruby)

```
# increment count for this temperature
if @temperature_hash[temperature]
  @temperature_hash[temperature] += 1
else
  @temperature_hash[temperature] = 1
end

# update mode if necessary
if @temperature_hash[temperature] > @max_occurrence
  @max_occurrence = @temperature_hash[temperature]
  @mode = temperature
end
```

Second, there's no particular reason to re-compute the mean with every insertion. You only need to mark it as dirty and re-compute it when next you query the mean. For a simple division, this isn't strictly necessary, but it could come in handy when a more complex operation is required. The code would be something like:

```
# for mean
@sum += temperature
@count += 1    
@meanDirty = 1
```

And when you query the mean:

```
if (@meanDirty == 1)
  @mean = @sum/@count
  @meadDirty = 0
end
return @mean
```